# SHAP DeepExplainer KeyError

Tags: deep-learning, tf.keras

I get an error when I use SHAP DeepExplainer.

Here is my code

```
explainer = shap.DeepExplainer((mlp.model().input, mlp.model().output), x_train.iloc[:100,:])

explanations = explainer.shap_values(x_test.iloc[:1,:])
```

Here is my model

```
class MLP(tf.keras.Model):
    
    def __init__(self, n_cols,**kwargs):
        super().__init__(**kwargs)
        print(n_cols)
        self._model = self.build_Model(n_cols)
    
    def build_Model(self, n_cols):
        model = Sequential()
        model.add(Dense(50,activation='relu', input_shape=(n_cols,), name='Dense1',kernel_initializer='glorot_normal',kernel_regularizer=keras.regularizers.l2(0.01))) # 150, I get 100% accuracy
        model.add(Dropout(rate=0.5)),
        model.add(Dense(50,activation='relu', name='Dense2',kernel_initializer='glorot_normal', kernel_regularizer=keras.regularizers.l2(0.01)))
        model.add(Dropout(rate=0.5)),
        model.add(Dense(1,activation='sigmoid', name='Dense3',kernel_initializer='glorot_normal',kernel_regularizer=keras.regularizers.l2(0.01)))
```

I get "KeyError: 0". Can you please help?[KeyError:0](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lfNbL.png)

Comment: Please edit your question to include error message text. [Images of code are not searchable](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-errors-when-asking-a-question).

Comment: @AlexanderL.Hayes, I have added the error message to my question. Does it look ok now?

Comment: When I used KernelExplainer, it is working =>  explainer = shap.KernelExplainer(mlp.model().predict, x_train[:100])